# C++ custom heterogeneous container through polymorphism and pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I'm writing a very simple and small wrapper around sqlite3, and use sqlite3_get_table() to fetch the results as `char**`. I use a base data class to be able to store the fields in a uniform container, namely record here, and then fetch each data type specifically using derived types.

This is my base class:

```
class data
{
    private:
        uint sz;
        virtual void abstract() = 0;

    public:
        inline data(char* pd);
        inline data();
        uint size() {return sz;}
};
```

and here's the sample derived class:

```
class str : public data
{
    private:
        string* pdata;
        virtual void abstract() {}

    public:
        inline str(char* pd);
        inline operator string();
        inline operator const char*();
};
```

and the record class:

```
class record
{
    private:
        ushort cols;
        data** entries;
    public:
        record(char** ppdata, uint col_count);
        inline data* operator [](ushort field);
        inline uint num_fields() {return cols;}
};
```

`record`'s `operator[]` (`inline data* operator [](ushort field);`) allows me to access the base `data` class this way:

`db::str* mys = dynamic_cast<db::str*>((*record)[3]);`

and compile: `g++ -o main -lsqlite3 main.cpp` under Arch Linux, and there's no problem in compilation. But when I run it I get `Segmentation Fault`.

Commenting out the dynamic_cast line makes me happy, but I personally guess I'm doing the downcast wrong in someway, rather than thinking there's a problem with definition or use of the `data` class.

I also appreciate any radical offenses to my code, since I know I'm a newbie. Thanks so much.

Comment: Where is this `record` class? Adding polymorphic behaviour should enable you to avoid the downcast.

Comment: I just added the record class. It does nothing other than containing pointers to `data`s.

Comment: @sje397 yes, I've aimed to add polymorphic behavior, but I should have gone the wrong way. I need your helps! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank both of you TC1 and Mark Ransom. I tried twiddling my problem and I finally came to realize that this is the best solution, comparing it's advantages to it's trade offs, for a simple wrapper like the one I'm writing (sqlite3's `sqlite3_get_table()`):

```
enum types {INT, FLOAT, STRING, BLOB, NUL};

class bad_type {};

class data
{
    private:
        void* pdata;
        types type;

    public:
        data(int dt)
        {
            int* tmp = new int(dt);
            pdata = static_cast<void*>(tmp);
            type = INT;
        }
        // constructors for other types to be added in a similar fashion.

        operator int()
        {
            if (type == INT)
                return *(static_cast<int*>(pdata));
            throw bad_type();
        }
        // operators for other types to be added in a similar fashion.
};
```

This way I'm making the data* a very suitable pointer type for making a heterogeneous container (Sorry that I didn't know the word when I asked the question ;-) ) in such a case that data types are limited, 5 in this case, since its working at a somehow low level.

I just used it in my test `main` like this:

```
data* array[3];
array[0] = new data(3);

cout << *(array[0]);
```

And it does give me `3`, and certainly its gotta be possible to apply it to any other type too, especially at low level in this case that types are often fundamental rather than say sophisticated inherited ones.

I've come to believe that in such cases `static_cast` can be tolerated, please correct me if I'm wrong. And also I'm really willing to know of both of your criticisms and appreciations about this solution, since it helps me learn more as a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to let you all know guys, that I've come to this conclusion that its the most foolish thing to do, to try to detect size and type of fields of an `sqlite3_get_table()` return result right from the result itself, since its `char**` :-D , but anyway the need for a good and deep understanding of how to implement a heterogeneous container gotta be addressed for perhaps any beginner. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dynamic_cast` you need to check the result to see if it's `NULL`. This occurs when the object isn't actually an instance of the type you tried to cast to.

Comment: I just replace the dynamic_cast line with `db::data* pd = (*r)[3];` and I don't get the segmentation fault error. `cout << pd;` in this case gives `0x21`.What should I do @Mark?

Comment: @ai64, you haven't included quite enough information in the question to know why `dynamic_cast` isn't working. That pointer value looks suspicious though. I'd look at the point where you're filling `r`.

Comment: I've never used G++, but do you need to enable RTTI in some way?  (Spot the Microsoft VS user.  :-) )

Comment: What I'm aiming to do simply is this: Store different types of data, string, int, float, blob, and none, in one uniform array, to be called record. What would you propose? I'm sure its a very common problem in CS and must have scientifically correct C++ solutions which I don't know of. Here I'm seeking the ansewr. Thank you.

Comment: @ai64 In developer studio, you can't use dynamic casts unless RunTime Type Information is enabled for the project.  I thought maybe there might be a command line option for this in G++ that you've neglected to use.  If the code you have works with a static cast, then that may well be the case.  If you're not checking the return from dynamic cast against null, you needn't bother using dynamic cast anyway.  And avoid using c-style casts!

Comment: @user1158692 gcc disables RTTI only in some certain conditions, notably (and that I know of), when it's explicitly turned off via `-fno-rtti`. It's enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing a `downcast`, you're doing an `upcast`. The `data` class is the base returned by `operator[]`, and you're casting it to `db::str*`, which is a child. Not every `data` is a `str`, so you should, for starters, check whether what you're trying to cast is a `str` and whether the cast doesn't return 0.

Also, you should get used to using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), in particular, the [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool of it. You could probably pinpoint the place and cause in a matter of seconds, and as an Arch user myself, I guarantee you it's in the repos. You run your program with `valgrind --tool=memcheck ./myprogram`.

Comment: I knew I should run into such a problem, so I disabled conversion to any type other than `str` so I could check to see if my design is correct. Yes, it is str, but how should I know the result is not 0? If you're talking about the pointer that isn't the case too as I've explained in comment on previous answer. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @ai64 If the result of the cast is not NULL, then it was successful and you have yourself a `str` object (well, pointer to one, actually). The problem is probably not in the line you mention then but somewhere further, where you use the `str` value you got. As I noted, you should really just run whatever you have with Valgrind, you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Ok I'll check that and let everyone know about it. Thanks.

Comment: Can't give an asnwer before going through valgrind's man page too.